# ports I open with iptables appear closed

Tags: debian, iptables, nmap

I opened the following ports with iptables on Debian 7:

```
iptables -X
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT #FTP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 111 -j ACCEPT #RPCBIND
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT #AUTH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT #NETBIOS-SSH
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT #HTTPS
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 901 -j ACCEPT #SAMBA
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT #IMAP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT #TOMCAT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT #PPTP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT #WEBMIN
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

But when I scan for open ports on my server with "nmap" some appear as closed. Can someone help me please?

```
~ $ nmap 172.16.17.135

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-21 14:38 PDT
Nmap scan report for 172.16.17.135
Host is up (0.00060s latency).
Not shown: 988 filtered ports
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp    open   ftp
22/tcp    open   ssh
80/tcp    open   http
111/tcp   open   rpcbind
113/tcp   closed ident
139/tcp   closed netbios-ssn
443/tcp   open   https
901/tcp   closed samba-swat
993/tcp   closed imaps
1723/tcp  closed pptp
8080/tcp  closed http-proxy
10000/tcp closed snet-sensor-mgmt
```

Comment: Do you have services running on those ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user3680708,

To list services with open ports:

```
# netstat -tulpn
```

That will list the PID and Service name with TCP/UDP information. If the service/port is not listed then this might explain why the port state is "closed" in your nmap scan.