# I cant open a port iptables - The command runs, but port keeps closed

Tags: iptables, opensuse, nmap

I want to make a simple redirect of my notebook port to a VM port (in my notebook also)..

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 2424 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2424 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.10:8000
```

In another machine in the network..

```
$ nmap 192.168.101.199

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-07-08 18:52 BRT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.101.199
Host is up (0.0027s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8000/tcp open  http-alt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.25 seconds
```

The telnet on notebook port 2424 doesn't works too.

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Is something actually listening on that port?  What do you see with `netstat -ntlp`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that default nmap scans that high. Try to use the -p switch to scan 2424 specifically. If I recall nmap only scans 1-1024 and certain higher services by default. There's 65535 ports nmap can potentially scan so scanning all by default would be laborious as hell.

EDIT: I checked documentation and I'm correct in that it scans 1-1024 and certain higher.

Comment: Thank you buddy.. But I run `nmap 192.168.101.199 -p 2424` and I get `2424/tcp closed unknown`.

Comment: Is there an actual service running on that port? Can you specify the service? @RafaelSoufraz

Comment: Nops.. There isn't any service in this port. I need just make a redirection.

Comment: So, to clarify (and basically like @zoredache) asked, is there anything at all currently listening on this port?

Comment: You probably will not see anything until something is actually running there.

Comment: So.. I have a VM and I need just a little redirect of this port to a specific port in this VM. I need a service either?

Comment: You need to setup NAT then and allow forwarding, not open a port to the host.

Comment: Only with iptables I can do that?

Comment: Bottom line is if nothing is running on this port, it will remain closed (verified by this post http://serverfault.com/questions/623180/ports-i-open-with-iptables-appear-closed?rq=1). If you do a port redirect, it depends on the actual situation. If you're reaching it over the internet you need to forward it through your router. For iptables specific forwarding, which wouldn't be sufficient in some situations, here's some reading http://www.systutorials.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz is your question solved? May be beneficial to provide details about the situation. You need the service to be running though to get actually picked up with nmap. Otherwise the host is gonna say "nothing is running on this port, so why would I accept this connection?"

Comment: Yes.. I found my specific solution.. I'll answer my own question. Thank you all.   :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I was wrong in my question.. My situation was a little different.
In my case, I have a notebook in my network and inside this guy I have a VM.
But.. This VM access internet via nat (using vitual box). Then, the others pcs in my network can't access this VM.
*Range my network: 192.168.0 - Range VM: 192.168.10*
What I wanted? Enable the access to a service in VM for all pcs in my network but through a port in my notebook.

Studying a little, I found my mistake.. When I make just a redirect of my notebook port 2424 to the VM port 8000 it 'works'. But the case was: my VM needs response to the network. How the VM will return something if it is out of my network?

So.. Beyond open a port and make the forwarding, I need to masquerade the response of VM in my notebook.
Everything that comes to my notebook port 2424 go to the VM port 8000. But when the VM return something, I need say to the request machine that who's responding is my notebook.  :)

After a lot of bla bla bla.. Follow the rulles:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 2424 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 2424 -j DNAT --to 192.168.10.10:8000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.10.10 --dport 8000 -j MASQUERADE
```

Thank you all!

Comment: If your question was wrong, **please edit your question to reflect your actual problem** before trying to answer it.